# How to play an exact part of MP3 file between given positions in ms?

Tags: c#, naudio

(Newbie question)

NAudio allows to start playing an MP3 file from a given position (by converting it from ms into bytes using `Waveformat.AverageBytesPerSecond`), but is it possible to make it **stop** playing exactly at another given position (in ms)? Do I have to somehow manipulate the wavestream or there are easier ways?

There is a solution using a `Timer` simultaneously together with starting playback and stopping playback after the timer ticks, but it doesn't produce reliable results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a custom `IWaveProvider` that only returns  a maximum of a specified number of bytes from `Read`. Then reposition your Mp3FileReader to the start, and pass it in to the custom trimming wave provider

Here's some *completely untested* example code to give you an idea.

```
 class TrimWaveProvider
 {
     private readonly IWaveProvider source;
     private int bytesRead;
     private readonly int maxBytesToRead;

     public TrimWaveProvider(IWaveProvider source, int maxBytesToRead)
     { 
         this.source = source;
         this.maxBytesToRead = maxBytesToRead;
     }

     public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return source.WaveFormat; } }

     public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bytesToRead)
     {
         int bytesToReadThisTime = Math.Min(bytesToRead, maxBytesToRead - bytesRead);
         int bytesReadThisTime = source.Read(buffer, offset, bytesToReadThisTime);
         bytesRead += bytesReadThisTime;
         return bytesReadThisTime;
     }
 }

 // and call it like this...
 var reader = new Mp3FileReader("myfile.mp3");
 reader.Position = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 3; // start 3 seconds in
 // read 5 seconds
 var trimmer = new TrimWaveProvider(reader, reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 5);
 WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
 waveOut.Init(trimmer);
```